# Preventing mobile data use for select apps on non-rooted phone?

Tags: rooting, data-connection, firewall

I have a number of apps that are fairly chatty on the network, and with a limited data connection I would like these apps to not use the 3G connection (WiFi is fine).

I know that [rooting the phone and installing DroidWall](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7976/how-do-i-enable-mobile-data-only-for-select-apps-on-a-rooted-phone) would do the trick. However, is there a way to accomplish per-app data permissions *without* rooting it?

FWIW, I have a Droid 1 on a CDMA network.

Comment: Related: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Answer (score 7):

Not quite answering your question, but switching off Background Data usage should stop chatty apps from doing anything in the background, and restrict it to just apps you launch and use, rather than apps that are syncing and checking for status updates all the time.

If you add the Power Control Bar (built into Android since 1.6) to your home screen it's just one tap to switch the background data on and off. Just hold your finger on an empty space on the home screen, select **Widgets**, **Power Control**, and the second icon from the right (two round arrows in a circle) controls the background data usage.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Android ICS, you can set the "Restrict background data" setting for each app. Go to `Settings > Data usage`, select the `Mobile` tab, then scroll down and select the app that you want to restrict. You can set the option at the bottom of the page that appears.

If an app is built properly, setting this option will disallow the widgets and background services of the app to access the internet via mobile data (but not via WiFi). If you launch the app it can access the internet via mobile data. 
Also note that not all apps play nice and some do not respect this setting.

Answer (score 1):

A firewall application is suitable for this task. There are other firewall options for non-root users:

1. [NetGuard firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard&hl=en) (no root )

Features:

- No root required
- Android 4.0 and later supported
- IPv4/IPv6 TCP/UDP supported
- Tethering supported
- Optionally block when roaming
- Optionally block system applications
- Optionally record network usage per application per address

Screenshots
[image: a]

2. [NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall&hl=en)

Features

- Host name/domain name filtering
- Fine-grained access control
- no suspicious permissions on the firewall app itself.

  (currently doesn't support IPv6) may not work on LTE.

Screenshots

[image: b]

Answer (score 1):

In Xiaomi phones it is possible to restrict background data in Security app from Mi.

You can also restrict background data for every app also!

I have used it many times when my left data is very less.

Don't know about other smartphones security app !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this [Opera Max](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.max.global&hl=en) app. Despite having a lot of features that you might use, the feature below mentioned is what you need right now.

**Block data-hungry apps** - Find out which apps use the most data - you can even choose to block them from using data altogether