# How to prevent specific apps from using mobile data?

Tags: mobile-data

So there are some mobile apps that love to use lots of mobile data, and sometimes use it when the wifi signal isn't good (e.g. Spotify). Which then leads to a nasty surprising spike in data usage during those times.

My phone is rooted, btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing mobile data use for select apps on non-rooted phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/preventing-mobile-data-use-for-select-apps-on-non-rooted-phone)

Comment: Sadly doesn't answer the question. :( The apps aren't using the data in the background, but often use it when wifi signal becomes weak and the phone autoswitches to 4G.

Comment: The answer is in the question itself. You are rooted. DroidWall should work for you. Can you try?

Comment: Yeah - just tried. Surprisingly, still doesn't work (doesn't allow me to go into options). I have a Galaxy S5

Comment: Try **Xprivacy** of xposed repository. I'm sure it must work. You need to use it carefully.

Comment: @InquilineKea Galaxy S5 has a [built-in feature](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LMHr3.png) called __Smart Network Switch__ which causes this. Go to WiFi -> _Uncheck_ this option.

Answer (score 3):

Android itself does not provide such a tool,
but you can use firewalls that require root,

---

- If your device is not rooted, so no problem, there are some applications that use some trick that can prevent apps from being connected to internet, such as [NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall&hl=en).

> The Trick of NoRoot Firewall is that it opens a Fake VPN connection
>   for making the phone to send all the packets to the Application then you
>   can define for the application which one to allow and which one to
>   deny.
>   So it does not require root access.

---

- If your device is rooted you can use [Droid Wall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&hl=en)  and it will do what you want.

---

you can download it from Google Play Store.

Note:I'm using NoRoot Firewall on My Xperia S and Xperia Z1 for a long time, even my Xperia S is rooted but i still use this application for blocking apps from being accessed to Internet.

Comment: Okay I'll try that.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Stock un-rooted Android has a feature in the "Data Usage" sections of Settings that shows you a sorted list of the apps consuming data.  For each app, there's a checkbox to block background usage of mobile data, but only allow background WiFi.  (To block foreground usage, don't run that app when you're not on WiFi...)

Comment: "(To block foreground usage, don't run that app when you're not on WiFi...)" What if I want to use the app offline but not have it use any data? (E.g.: Spotify)

Comment: disable wifi and mobile data globally then

Comment: This is not enough. When I use the Google Duo app, if it thinks the Wi-Fi quality is bad, it will switch to using cell data for video calls--even though the phone UI shows that the Wi-Fi is connected!

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool in your mobile data setting that is turned on by default that makes this happen. Go into data settings and uncheck the box.

Comment: That option disables the background data for all apps -_-