# How to monitor network traffic on Android with root access?

Tags: networking, logging

I want to monitor network traffic on my rooted Android device.

I found an app called "Network Log" ([repo](https://github.com/pragma-/networklog)), but it's outdated, designed for old Android versions, and has some bugs (but not critical). The app captures every packet using iptables, so it requires root.

Can the approach be replicated without an app? Otherwise, are there other apps?

Comment: That would be a fitting question for our sister site Sorftware Recommendations – see: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable Mobile Data only for select apps on a rooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246711)